# Best practice for URL's architectural Design in Django

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, django-urls

I have been designing websites with Django for a while and I have also designed various sites. **But here is a question that comes to mind at the beginning of any new project:**

> What is the **best a URLs architectural Design** that creates both
> **logical and meaningful** URLs path as well as **plugable apps**?

**Parctical Example And Problem**

I will explain my question with a practical example. Suppose that we have project with these features:

1. It has three applications called `Shop`, `Blog` and `Support`.
2. It has three `URL` section:

   2.1. Public section: that start with `/`.

   2.2. Consumer panel: that start with `/panel`.

   2.3. Administrator panel: that start with `/administrator`.
3. Each application has 3 views. For example `Shop` has: `public_shop_view`, `panel_shop_view` and `administrator_shop_view`.

**Now, What is the best `URL` design for this project?** I common solution to this answer:

**Solution:**

```
project/urls.py
    path('', include('Shop.urls', namespce='Shop')),
    path('', include('Blog.urls', namespce='Blog')),
    path('', include('Support.urls', namespce='Support')),
Shop/urls.py
    path('shop/', views.public_shop_view, name='public_shop_view'),
    path('panel/shop/', views.panel_shop_view, name='panel_shop_view'),
    path('administrator/shop/', views.administrator_shop_view, name='administrator_shop_view'),

Blog/urls.py
    path('blog/', views.public_blog_view, name='public_blog_view'),
    path('panel/blog/', views.panel_blog_view, name='panel_blog_view'),
    path('administrator/blog/', views.administrator_blog_view, name='administrator_shop_view'),

Support/urls.py
    path('support/', views.public_support_view, name='public_support_view'),
    path('panel/support/', views.panel_support_view, name='panel_support_view'),
    path('administrator/support/', views.administrator_support_view, name='administrator_support_view'),
```

**Now, What is the best practice? Is there any other solution?**

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Answer (score 2):

Its completely your own choice of selecting the approach... Key point is to keep our code modular enough to be reusable which can be obtained in first approach as every application have its own urls.Py file and can be used in other projects as well by simply importing app or mudules.... So to conclude silution 1 can make your app plugable...